# networking technologies other than sockets

Tags: networking

I wonder if there exist any other technologies used to establish internet connection between applications. Are there any other? I am searching and so far I haven't found anything else described.

Comment: please try [this tutorial](http://cf16.posterous.com/tcpip-tutorial-85977) - it might be useful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many abstractions on top of sockets, if you don't want to deal directly with a socket API.  UDP, TCP/IP, various RPC protocols, HTTP (which is on top of TCP/IP), etc.  Many programming languages have easy methods of doing, say, an HTTP request and getting the resulting document.  You can use that to allow applications to talk to each other over the internet without using a socket API.

What are you trying to accomplish?

If you want to skip sockets you basically have to implement your own means of talking to the network card hardware and telling it to communicate with other devices.  A socket is just the abstraction chosen for *nix and Windows machines.

Comment: UDP and TCP are not different technologies but just a communication protocols used by sockets in fact. Yes, so socket is just an interface, in fact it is just a half-association <protocol, local-address, local-process> as I just found in IBM tutorial, ofcourse it is a handle, file descriptor too, I know. I still don't feel it strong enough although, need a reading :D   you can check this [tutorial](http://cf16.posterous.com/tcpip-tutorial) from IBM - it is really useful for me

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "technology". Different protocols can count if that's the level your looking at. I think in order to answer the question we need more info about what you are trying to do, or is this just for general knowledge? You could look at the whole stack of Internet architecture, socket is just at one of those, specifically the interface between the OS and the application, sitting on top of the transport protocol layer.